# accessing fields across a package

Tags: java, android

How do I make fields accessible across a package? Currently, even if they are declared public i'm not able to access the fields from another class in the same package.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Pls post code which represents your problem.

Comment: You should be able to access them if they are in the same package - can you please post some code (the 2 classes in question).

Comment: Probably you need the import on those classes.

Comment: i goes with Pentium10. else that we can create an object for that class.you can use obj.fieldname;. like this. you may check that the field/variable declares as private.

Comment: @Pentium10 - you should not need to import a class if it is in the same class as this one.

Comment: here is my code:

class A extends Activity{
public boolean flag = false;
}
class B extends ListActivity{
if(flag)//error here:flag cannot be resolved
}

A and B belong to the same package and I've also included the line 
import org.example.Myapp.A in the B.java file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more apposite example.  (Based on @Andreas_D's example ... as if it ain't obvious!)

Note that an import is **not** needed to refer to a class declared in the same package.

```
package pkg;

public class One {
  public int fieldOne;
}
```

---

```
package pkg;

public class Two {
  private One one;
  public int getOne() {
    return one.fieldOne;
  }
}
```

---

Having said this, referring to public attributes declared in another class is generally a bad idea.  It is better to declare the attributes as private and access them via getter and setter methods.  (If the attributes are exposed as public and they are not final, that anything can modify them.  Furthermore, there is no way that a subclass can hide the attributes, or change the way that they behave.)

**EDIT**

To illustrate the last point:

```
public class A {
   public int counter;
   private int counter2;
   public int getCounter2() { return counter2; }
   public void setCounter2(int c) { counter2 = c; }
}

public class B extends A {
   public void setCounter2(int c) {
      if (c < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("counter2 cannot be negative");
      super.setCounter2(c); 
   }
}
```

Compare the way that the `counter` and `counter2` attributes behave.  In the case of `counter`, any code in any class can read or update the attribute without restriction.  This applies both for instances of the class `A` and any classes that extend `A`.  If some other class decides to set `counter` to a bad value ... there's nothing to prevent it.

In the case of `counter2`, the attribute of an instance of `A` can only be read or updated by the `getCounter2` and `setCounter2` methods respectively.  If I want to, I can change these methods in `A` to do validation, perform access checks, notify some listener of a state change an so on.  And because this behavior can only occur in methods of `A`, I know where to start looking in the event of something strange happening.

If I define a subclass of `A` (e.g. `B`), I can **override** either or both of the methods to do something different.  But note that since I decided to declare the actual attribute as `private`, the `setCounter2` method in B still has to call the method in its superclass.  And that's good too.

Comment: Point noted. But, can't I have a public member in class A that can be directly accessed by class B(i mean without the need for a instance of class A). Classes A and B belong to the same package.
According to acccess privileges, this should be possible right?

Comment: @Namratha - yes that's right.  Did you try to compile my example?

Comment: yes. your code compiled fine. I just don't understand why I'm having a problem. Please see my code below.
here is my code: class A extends Activity{ public boolean flag = false; } class B extends ListActivity{ if(flag)//error here:flag cannot be resolved } A and B belong to the same package and I've also included the line import org.example.Myapp.A in the B.java file

Comment: I can't access the fields without instantiation, can I?
If I have to, I'd have to make it static? how can I make a String variable static?

Comment: I got it. Just affix 'static' before String.
I don't want to use any instance coz then whatever manipulations I do has to be with that instance only. Am I right?

Comment: @Namratha - that is correct.  However, my point about public changeable attributes still stands ... and public mutable statics are even worse an idea.

Comment: All right. Say I use getter and setter methods in class A. Now, in order to access the fields of class A, I have to call the getter and setter on an instance. I don't want to handle any instances. So then, I'd have to declare it static and consequently even the fields have to be static.

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: @Namratha - two solutions.  1)  Make the getters and setters and the private field `static`.  2) The better option is to get over your *obsession* with not using instances.  You save almost nothing by doing that, and you lose a lot in terms of flexibility and adaptability of your software.

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by 'Furthermore, there is no way that a subclass can hide the attributes, or change the way that they behave.'?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should compile. Class Two has access to the field in class One. Please check your own if there is a difference.

```
package one;

public class A {
  public int fieldA;
}
```

---

```
package two;
import one.A;

public class B {
  private A a;
  public int getA() {
    return a.fieldA;
  }
}
```

Comment: That should be `import one.One;`  And using the same name for a package and an attribute in the same class is unnecessarily confusing.